# Can't make atoi take in a string (string vs. C-string?)

Tags: c++, string, file-io, atoi

I have read a line from a file and I am trying to convert it to an int. For some reason `atoi()` (convert string to integer) won't accept a `std::string` as an argument (possibly some issue with strings vs c-strings vs char arrays?) - how do I get `atoi()` to work right so I can parse this text file? (going to be pulling lots of ints from it).

Code:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    // string filename = "data.txt";
    // ifstream file(filename)
    ifstream file("data.txt");
    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        int columns = atoi(line);
    }
    file.close();
    cout << "Done" << endl;
}
```

The line causing problems is:

```
int columns = atoi(line);
```

which gives the error:

> error: cannot convert `'std::string'` to `'const char*'` for argument '1' to 'int `atop(const char*)`'

How do i make atoi work properly?

EDIT: thanks all, it works! new code:

```
int main()
{
string line;
//string filename = "data.txt";
//ifstream file (filename)
ifstream file ("data.txt");
while ( getline (file,line) )
{
  cout << line << endl;
  int columns = atoi(line.c_str());
  cout << "columns: " << columns << endl;
  columns++;
  columns++;
  cout << "columns after adding: " << columns << endl;
}
file.close();
cout << "Done" << endl;
}
```

also wondering why 
    string filename = "data.txt";
    ifstream file (filename)
fails, but

```
    ifstream file("data.txt");
```

works?
( I will eventually be reading filename form the command line so need to make it not a string literal)

Comment: Never ever use atoi. It can not report errors. Use either std::strtoi, or even better, std::stoi.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Exactly, but you mean `strtol`. `boost::lexical_cast` might also be an option. There *is* a question on all of this somewhere IIRC.

Comment: atoi not reporting errors seems beneficial, it tries to work even if something goes wrong, rather than throwing an exception at me and quitting.  From www.cplusplus.com, found that atoi is good because "No-throw guarantee: this function never throws exceptions."

Comment: @user2333388, That's bad. That means you have no idea whether it succeeded or not, whether you want to know or not. If you want to ignore bad conversions, you can always add an empty catch block. Most of the time, pretending it worked will end painfully.

Comment: @user2333388: Yeah, people that input strings into your program will love it that it silently use 0 instead of whatever value they wanted to give and just made a type, and they will surely not wonder why the heck the program doesn't do what they intended.

Comment: hmm, that does make sense, though in this case it is a very specific file so should be able to check by hand if it worked.  That said, this is a good general point, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The c_str method exists for this purpose.

```
int columns = atoi(line.c_str());
```

BTW your code should read

```
while (getline (file,line))
{
    ...
```

Just because the file is 'good' does not mean the *next* getline will succeed, only that the *last* getline succeeded. Use getline directly in your while condition to tell if you did actually read a line.

Comment: it works - thanks!  BY the way, any idea why                     string filename = "data.txt";
 ifstream file(filename)                                               fails but ifstream file("data.txt"); works?

Comment: Same solution `ifstream file(filename.c_str());` Although I think in C++11 you can use a string too. There is an automatic conversion from char* to string, but not the other way around. It's the way the string class was designed.

Answer (score 2):

`int columns = atoi(line.c_str());`

Answer (score 1):

Use `line.c_str()` instead of just `line`

This atoi takes a `const char*` not a `std::string`